# Simple contact form validation with IF statements in PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have made a contact form in HTML5 and I would like to validate It with PHP. I used a method what was show by *Brad Hussey* in a UDEMY course. So I got the data with a POST method. Then comes this code:

```
if ($_POST) {

    if (!$_POST['nev']) {
        $error .= "Kérem töltse ki a név mezőt!<br>";
    }

    if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $error .= "Kérem adja meg az email címet!<br>";
    }

    if ($_POST['email'] && STfilter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $error .= "A(z) $emailcim cím nem valós";
    } 

    if ($error != "") {
        $error ='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Hiba lépett fel!<br>' . $error . '</div>';
    } else {
        $nev = $_POST['nev'];
        $emailcim = $_POST['email'];

        include 'phpmailer.php';        
    }

}
```

The phpmailer.php works fine if I rune it alone. And If I skip the validation and go directly to phpmailer.php everything is okay. So the problem should be inside this 3 IF statements, just I can't figure It out :(

Do you have any idea?

update: Sorry I didn't write down well the problem. It is just simple white page. So when I click to the submit button, It doesn't send the mail, and not going back to the site. It became a totaly empty page. Something like when I miss a ; sign. But I checked It many times (with syntax checker too), and nothing is missing.

I think the problem could be somewhere here:

```
  if ($_POST['email'] && STfilter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    $error .= "A(z) $emailcim cím nem valós";
}
```

I don't really understand the working of this part.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: What does this have to do with Bootstrap?

Comment: "*..So the problem should be inside this 3 IF statements*" **WHAT PROBLEM?**

Comment: Question is unclear. Also what's `STfilter_var`? Remove ST prefix.

Comment: What are you doing with `$error´ later in your code?

Comment: Thanks the STfilter vas the problem. I just copied the code, not realy understanded the working method of this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuğca Eker was right!

The problem was the `STfilter_var`prefix.

The correct statement is this:

```
if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
$error .= "A(z) $emailcim cím nem valós"; 
}
```